# What is proper methodology for creating a mood board for a logo design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

There exists a fair amount of references online on how to create mood boards using various online services. I'm looking to create a mood board that has a visual hierarchy, incorporated's colors, shapes and images.

However, I have not been able to find a good tutorial for Illustrator. There plenty for Photoshop. Any thoughts or recommendations on the proper methodology?

Comment: Whilst there probably is a general thought process that you can follow, I don't think there is a set method for this. I look forward to the answers though. :)

Comment: Just curious, but why cant the same process you've seen in Photoshop not be implemented in Illustrator?

Comment: There are no rules as to what a mood board has to be or how to put it together beyond it being a collection of visuals that are attempting to help communicate a particular 'mood'.

Comment: Please do not use the answer field for an extension of the question. You can edit you original question and are encouraged to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X Mojave has a Moodboard app.

Good Luck!!
B

Comment: Hi there! We try to avoid link-only answers, because links can go down. Can you add some of the content in here, so the answer remains valid even if the links die?

Comment: yeah I will try to figure out the best way to do that cleanly... lotta content there.